# Wordpress website menu is not openning in mobile view

Tags: wordpress, menu

I have created my wordpress website. It is using suarez theme.Menu is working in desktop but not working in mobile view.When click menu icon menu is not open
Here is my site: https://jaxonlabs.com/

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, you have two menus probably, one for desktop, another for mobile.

the mobile menu apparently hidden by default, and when displayed on mobile, the mobile menu shows up and the desktop menu gets hidden.

check in your admin panel for mobile menu in Appearance->Menus and fill it with the pages,links, and categories you want, and save it.

Comment: I have created menu by adding pages and links. But in mobile it is not working

Comment: @Priya i have checked the demo from theme forest, and it works fine. did you add the menu to mobile menu? i guess that the issue is not code related.

Comment: How to add menu in mobile menu?

Comment: I have created menu in Appearence->Menu. Same for the desktop and mobile?

Comment: @Priya you figured it out? how many menus do you see? and what are their names?

Comment: I want only one menu and want to show on both desktop and mobile view

Comment: @Priya so does it has a separate menu for mobile? if so, locate its code and replace it with the one with desktop menu. but this code not be good for the styling, also having a separate menu for mobile is not bad, just replicate the items.

Answer (score 0):

The reason seems to be that the mobile menu is empty with nothing in it:

```
<div id="cshero-main-menu-mobile" class="navbar-collapse cshero-mmenu collapse in"></div>
```

If you add `<ul>` and insert some dummy `<li>` items using Inspector, the menu shows up.

My guess is that the mobile menu code uses [wp_nav_menu()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/) function with *menu* parameter that does not exist, so it renders nothing. Try to locate it in the theme and compare the parameters if they match the menu you added in  **Appearance > Menus**.